# Error in Build - Missing SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, sample

I downloaded some Application samples from a website.
It used to work but when I went back to Xcode (After a couple of months) I tried them and it gives me this error.

> error: There is no SDK with the name
>   or path 'iphoneos2.0'

I tried looking for a file called "iphoneos2.0"
and tried looking for a highlighted code but nothing.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The *Base SDK* of your downloaded app's *Target* has set to *iphoneos2.0*. Change the *Base SDK* of the *Target* from *iphoneos2.0* to a iOS version which is available.

*To change the Build Settings in (Xcode 3.2)* - Goto **Project -> Edit Project Settings** menu. Or, **Double-click the project name in the project tree in Xcode**.

*To change the Build Settings in (Xcode 4)* - **Select the project name in the project tree**. It will open the **Project Settings** in the document area of Xcode.

In the project settings, search for *Base SDK*.

Comment: I found in the menu iphoneos2.0(missing) , iphoneos3.2 , iphoneos4.0" I chose iphoneos3.2 it said =                    "BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
[BWARN]warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'."

Comment: @VBCodeStudent, It is the provisioning profile mismatch error. Goto the project settings and change the **Code Signing Identity** to **Don't Code Sign** if you want to run the project in Simulator, or change it to any other provisioning profile if you already have any provisioning profile. We need provisioning profile to run an app in device.

Comment: Now it says :           
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 4.0'

Comment: @VBCodeStudent, You want to run this in Simulator?

Comment: @VBCodeStudent, In Xcode, above the project tree, you can see a pop-up-button showing the target to a iOS device. In that change the target to a simulator version.